# How to make t-sne plots with BERT Models

Tags: nlp, text-classification, tsne

[image]

I have two text classification models
https://huggingface.co/samanjoy2/banglaclickbert_finetuned_sequence_classification_clickbait
https://huggingface.co/samanjoy2/banglabert_finetuned_sequence_classification_clickbait

I want to plot their hidden states in a T-SNE plor. How can I do this? A example of this has been shown in the picture.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, I'll encourage you to ask the question here in the discussion instead https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions. Most probably the questions would be flagged as "asking for tool/fix recommendation" as it is now.

Comment: will [this](https://www.kaggle.com/code/mateiionita/visualizing-bert-embeddings-with-t-sne) be of any help?